# SpringBoot external jar not load

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

i have a java project with spring boot and I need to load application.properties and dependency jar from external folder.

I tested by using the application.properties in the classpath, and the loader.path property work correctly.

When I use external properties file (I'm sure they're used) the loader.path not work correctly and the result is ClassNotFound because the jars are not loaded.

Also when i launch the application with **-Dloader.path=**xxx it's work correctly.

How can I solve the problem using external properties and jar?

Comment: you can refer to [Launching Executable Jars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-launching) for  detail

Comment: can you post your `main` method and how you start your application with external properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

1. You need to make sure the load order of different property files.
2. You need to make sure the loader.path points to the right path. I mean, relative path or absolute path? You'd better print it out.