# How to add external JARs to Spring application without restarting JVM?

Tags: java, spring-boot, plugins, dynamic-loading

I have a Spring Boot application which copies external JAR files to a folder, depending on certain conditions. These JARs can contain many Spring components (i.e. classes annotated or meta-annotated with `@Component`) and the Spring application should be able scan and instantiate for these beans. Is it possible, based on certain conditions, to *dynamically* load the contents of the JAR files and make them available to the Spring application context? *I am fully aware of the security implications this has.*

I have read about the different types of `Launcher`s which Spring provides for its [executable JAR format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar), such as [`JarLauncher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.html) and [`PropertiesLauncher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.html), but it looks like that these launchers do not detect changes to the classpath, but instead only scan the directories once for JAR files.

The following simple application demonstrates the problem:

```java
// .../Application.java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please copy JAR files and press Enter ...");
    System.in.read();
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Replace the default `JarLauncher` with `PropertiesLauncher`:

```
// build.gradle
tasks.named('bootJar') {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher',
      'Start-Class': 'com.example.customlauncher.Application'
  }
}
```

Specify the location to the external JARs in the properties file of the `PropertiesLauncher`:

```
# .../resources/loader.properties
loader.path=file:/path/to/dir
```

The application is a [Spring Initializer Gradle application](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.2.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=customlauncher&name=customlauncher&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.customlauncher) and packaged by running the `bootJar` task: `./gradlew bootJar`.

It is then started with the following command:

```sh
java -jar build/libs/customlauncher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This works if the JAR file is already present at the specified location (`/path/to/dir`), but it does not work if the `java` command is executed while the directory is empty and the JAR file is then copied while the app waits for the user to copy the files and press Enter <kbd>↲</kbd>.

There are a couple of related questions, but it looks like they all assume that the JAR files already exist at the time of starting the JVM:

- [How to put a directory first on the classpath with Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427745/how-to-put-a-directory-first-on-the-classpath-with-spring-boot)
- [Spring Boot Executable Jar with Classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716796/spring-boot-executable-jar-with-classpath)
- [SpringBoot external jar not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649692/springboot-external-jar-not-load)

Is there a way to achieve this without too many awkard hacks? Or is recommended to utilize something like [OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715118/how-to-dynamically-load-java-classes-at-runtime-in-osgi-framework)? Am I looking at this completely wrong and there is a better way to have JARs on the classpath that do not need always need loading (if the JAR is "disabled", it should not be loaded/compiled by the JVM, should not be picked up by Spring, etc.)?

Comment: I implemented something similar without spring. I was able to load any jar (plugins) after the start of the main application. Is this an option for you?

Comment: @JRichardsz: yes please, if you can share that as an answer, it would be super helpful for me and any future visitors. In my case it just happened to be a Spring application, but the problem is not limited to Spring applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is possible if the JAR files are copied before starting the Spring application. It feels hackish, but it works. **Use at your own risk!**

You need two classes, one for bootstrapping the external JARs, which will then start the second via a manually created `PropertiesLauncher`. The bootstrapping class can be a plain old regular Java class (but it can be a Spring Boot Application too) and only the second class needs to be a SpringBootApplication.

```java
// BootstrapApplication.java
public class BootstrapApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please copy JAR files and press Enter ...");
    System.in.read();

    PropertiesLauncher.main(args);
  }
}
```

```java
// Application.java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

In the gradle file, we can switch back to the default `JarLauncher`, by removing the `bootJar` task manifest configuration and applying settings via the `springBoot` configuration block. `mainClass` will end up as `Start-Class` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file.

```
// build.gradle
springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.example.customlauncher.BootstrapApplication'
}
```

In the properties file for the loader, a new property needs to be set, which points to the real application class. The settings in this file are only picked up by `PropertiesLauncher` and ignored by `JarLauncher`. In other words: `JarLauncher` delegates to `Start-Class` from the manifest file and `PropertiesLauncher` delegates to `loader.main` from its properties file.

```
# .../resources/loader.properties
loader.path=file:/path/to/dir
loader.main=com.example.customlauncher.Application
```

Spring (Boot) will first call the main method of `BootstrapApplication`, as specified in the `MANIFEST.MF` file (controlled via `springBoot` configuration block in the `build.gradle` file). In the implementation of this main method, a new `PropertiesLauncher` is created with the main class set to the "real" application (i.e. `Application`).

Executing the application is still done via the same invocation:

```sh
java -jar build/libs/customlauncher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Any JAR files added to `/path/to/dir` after the JVM has started, but *before* calling `PropertiesLauncher#main` in BootstrapApplication are then available in the classpath and application context as seen from `Application`.

Comment: PropertiesLauncher is not working in case of deploying spring boot war in external tomcat. Any Suggestion on this?